# How to change the Schema of a table inside the stored procedures dynamically

Tags: sql-server

We have changed the table schema and we need to change the schema name in all the procedures that table being used dynamically instead of manual replace.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What didn't work? If your project is in a source Control (hopefully it is), you could presumably just do a huge find and replace in the project. `Ctrl+H` type `dbo.YourTableName` in Find, type `newschema.YourTableName` in Replace. `Ctrl+A`.

Comment: You might (possibly) be able to get it to work using a synonym. See [here](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-synonym/).

Comment: Please explain the reason why you would like to do that. If you really have a good reason for doing such things, a better approach is to pass the schema name as a parameter to the SP or use a synonym.

Answer (score 0):

If you would use SSDT for database development, you could utilise its refactoring capability of doing [just that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/how-to-use-rename-and-refactoring-to-make-changes-to-your-database-objects). Of course, any dynamic SQL will be left untouched, so if you have it in your code modules, you will need to search for it as usual.

If you don't plan to switch over to SSDT, you can create a database project, import schema from any existing database, perform any necessary refactoring and then deploy changes back to the database, either via a generated deployment script, or by using [Schema Compare](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/how-to-use-schema-compare-to-compare-different-database-definitions).